# Three divs with different width side by side, those left and right fixed

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">

    </div>

    <div id="middle">

    </div>

    <div id="right">

    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 1000px;  
    position: relative; 
    background-color: yellow; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}

    #left{
        width: 200px; 
        height: 50px;  
        position: fixed; 
        float: left; 
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #middle{
        width: 200px; 
        height: 5000px; 
        margin-left: 30px; 
        float: left; 
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right{
        width: 500px; 
        height: 50px;  
        position: fixed; 
        float: right; 
        background-color: green;
    }
```

I want only the middle div to be scrolled when it's higher than the screen, how can I do this? I already searched for similar questions but didn't find this specific problem.

Comment: Are you using any CSS framework. If bootstrap then which version?

Comment: No I don't use any frameworks

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. Using [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/vr7b15pf/) it looks like your red bar is scrolling. Are you wanting the contents to scroll? I also am not able to see your left div so I'm unsure if that's intentional or not

Comment: @MickelsonMichael I want the divs side by side, not overlapping each other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS -align 3 responsive Divs- left right with position fixed and center normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441688/css-align-3-responsive-divs-left-right-with-position-fixed-and-center-normal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the position: sticky; property, although the browser support isn't the best: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}

.center {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, .2) 0, rgba(255, 255, 0, .2) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    Center
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I see from the comments to the other answers that you want to have full control of the widths. I used flex to line up the elements so you should be able to change any width without breaking anything.

Comment: I had to remove my comment because it's still not working properly in my case. Why is left and right div move couple of pixels up when I start scrolling and then stops instead of keeping the position to begine with? In my case a part of the content in those divs disappear when I start scroping, how to fix that?

Comment: They start moving because the body has a default padding, I removed it in my example now. I can't say why it's not working in your project without seeing the full code.

Comment: I just figured it out, the top property says how much the margin should be to the top of the viewport so I changed top:0 to top:80px which is height of header + 
desired margin to it. It's all good now thanks again! :D

Answer (score 2):

```css
#container{
    width: 100%;  
    position: relative; 
    background-color: yellow;
}

    #left{
        width: 33.3%; 
        height: 50px;  
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #middle{
        width: 33.3%; 
        height: 5000px; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        background-color: red;
    }

    #right{
        width: 33.3%; 
        height: 50px;  
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">

    </div>

    <div id="middle">

    </div>

    <div id="right">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope.. I need container to be 1000px instead of 100% and the divs have different widths. I guess it's just not possible?

Comment: @EduardUnruh just set the width to 1000px in this example and your widths to different percentages?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float and add `top:0` and `right:0` to your right div and `margin:0 auto;` to middle div

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
#left{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;  
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: blue;
  
    
}

#middle{
    width: calc(100% - 200px); /* minus width of right and left div */
    height: 5000px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

#right{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px;  
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: green;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">

    </div>

    <div id="middle">

    </div>

    <div id="right">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The right div will jump out of #container and in case the right div would be 500px and others 200px then the right one would overlay the one in middle

Comment: @EduardUnruh I have updated the solution. use `calc()` . This will work even if you give container width to 1000px;

Comment: It's not working when right div got more width than others and it also still jump out of container